# Install Snipping Tool on Windows Server 2008 R2 without Desktop Experience

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, installation

What I would like to accomplish is to install the [**Snipping Tool**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Use-Snipping-Tool-to-capture-screen-shots) (most of you probably recognize this feature from Windows 7 and Vista), on a **Windows Server 2008 R2**.

This can be done by installing the [Desktop Experience](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772567.aspx) feature.

What I would like to know is: ***Is there any way I can install the Snipping Tool alone?*** Without having to install the other components in the Desktop Experience feature (like Defender, Themes, Windows Media Player), for which I have no use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just tried a few different ways to get this to work, including copying the executable from another install, and it won't launch no matter what I try. I can only assume that there is some dependency of the desktop compositing engine (DWM) that is also enabled when installing the Desktop Experience role.

Unfortunately, it seems like you're probably going to have to install everything and just disable Defender and ignore themes.